# Select first or last element of descendant

Tags: css, css-selectors

**I want to select only the first (or last) element with the class `media`.**

I can't add other classes to any of the html, it has to be CSS only. The other divs in the section are different types of content, not related to my `media`. I can't touch these either.

My plan is to add a top border only for the first div with the `media` class. Also the amount of divs with `stuff` is not set, and can be any amount. Also the amount of divs with `stuff` and `media` inside can be any. However the pattern stays the same.

This is how my html looks like:

```
    <section>
     <div class="stuff"></div>
     <div class="stuff"></div>  
     <div class="stuff">
      <div class="media"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="stuff">
       <div class="media"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="stuff"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: if the structure is random, there is no way with CSS .. consider JS/jQuery

Comment: @TemaniAfif the structure is not random, only the amount of divs with the class `media` is random

Comment: `only the amount of divs with the class media is random` --> so the whole structure is random :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif The `<div class="stuff"><div class="media"></div></div>` is one thing that gets generated, so there could be any amount of these. Also I don't understand why you marked it as duplicate

Comment: i marked as duplicate because it's a common case where people want to select a specific element (in your case the first and the last) using class and this is not possible with CSS ... the only way to select child is using nth-child or nth-of-type .. and the duplicate explain that you cannot combine this using class

Comment: so there is no in CSS something that allow you to : select the nth child element that have a specific class (including the first and/or the last) UNLESS your structure is well defined and not random

Comment: @TemaniAfif No I want to select either the first or last. Not both.

Comment: the first OR the last or Both of them ..  the second one, the before last one, etc, etc ... all the same logic ... you cannot target nth element using class if you have a structure that you cannot control